# Swift Firebase How do I add a custom branch to my user?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a custom branch that lists all friends for a user. Currently, I have the code to add a user's email and name (see user1 in the photo below).

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: FIREBASE_GAME)



        let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)




        let values = ["name" : name, "email" : email]

        usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in



            if(err != nil) {

                print(err!)

                return

            }
```

Would I add "friends" as a key in my values dictionary and then let the value be a sub-branch? I don't know what that would look like in code. I made user2 manually in Firebase (this is what I want to do in code). I'm new to Firebase and most resources give very basic examples. I would appreciate any help.

[image: u]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
let values = ["name" : name, "email" : email, "friends": [ "jake": false, "mike": true ]]

usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
    if(err != nil) {
        print(err!)
        return
    }
```

Alternatively, you can write/update the friends with a separate call:

```
usersReference.child("friends").updateChildValues(["jake": false, "mike": true])
```

Comment: Okay cool. Thanks! So when I update values, do they get appended to the array? Or do I need to copy the array reference, append the new friend, THEN update with this array?

Comment: The `friends` are not an indexed array, but a dictionary. This means that each key in it is unique, and you can add a friend with `usersReference.child("friends").updateChildValues(["nick": true])`

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model Class in Below Format. You need to change the object Friend in your Firebase Console.

```
class ListModel: NSObject {
    var UID:String?
    var Name:String?
    var Email:String?
    var Friends:[Friend]?
}

class Friend : NSObject {
   var Name : String?
   var Status : Bool?
}
```

In Your View Controller you can access using below Code

```
var Obj : ListModel?
var ListArr = [ListModel]()



let ref = Database.database().reference().child(“users”)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] 
else {
                return
            }

            let Obj = ListModel()
            Obj.UID = snapshot.key
            Obj.Name = dictionary["name"] as? String
            Obj.Email = dictionary["email"] as? String

            let friendsArr  = dictionary[“friends”] as? NSArray
            var friendObj = [Friend]()
            if friendsArr != nil{
                for dict in friendsArr as! [[String: AnyObject]]  {
                    let friend = Friend)
                    friend.Name = dict["name"] as? String
                    friend.Status = dict["mobile"] as? Bool
                    friendObj.append(friend)
                }
            }
            Obj. friendsArr = friendObj
            self.ListArr.append(Obj)




}, withCancel: nil)
```